# Passing the JavaScript variables by reference

Tags: javascript

I'm a bit confused about passing the JavaScript variables by reference.

Take the following piece of code:

```
var p = [1,2];
var pRef = p;
p.push(3);
pRef === p; // true
```

Then consider the following piece of code:

```
var s = "ab";
var sRef = s;
s = s + "c";
sRef === s; // false
```

what is the trick about passing the JavaScript variables by reference?

Does it exist a way to create a reference to a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manipulating the string causes the creation of a new instance of a string object. Pushing items in an array does not create a new instance of the array but only adds an item to it.

Comment: "Manipulating the string causes the creation of a new instance of a string object." And assigning the new instance to the variable makes it point to that new object.

Answer (score 2):

The two examples are not doing the same thing.  In the first case, you never reassign `p`, you simply call methods on it to modify the values within the array.  In the second case, you reassigned `s` after setting `sRef` so they are no longer equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

p is not representing [1,2] but a pointer from where [1,2] is save in memory.
So if you change p, or pRef, the place where this array is save in memory will not change only its value will.

Comment: The same can be said about the String variable, too, though.

Answer (score 0):

Objects are passed around by reference. If you want a function to manipulate a string by reference, you can pass that string on an object

```
function manipulate(obj) {
    obj.bar += ' changed';
}

var foo = {
   bar: 'that';
};

manipulate(foo);

//foo.bar is now 'that changed'
```

So all objects are passed by reference. Arrays are objects in js.